# Redis-sorted set to return the values for all keys in the sorted sets in Java

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I have Redis sorted set with key:ID and score: timestamp, and for that sorted set there is a hash with key:ID and all the other key:value pairs from a json object. I need to return the key:value pairs from the hash, but sorted by timestamp which is in the sorted set.

Here is my code:
Service:

```
    private final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    public LatestInitsServiceImpl(LatestInitsRepository latestInitsRepository, RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
        this.latestInitsRepository = latestInitsRepository;
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }
    public Set<Object> readSortedSetIDsByScoreAsc(String key, long minScore, long maxScore) {
        return redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScore(key, minScore, maxScore);
    }

    @Override
    public List<LatestInits> getValuesForKeys(String sortedSetKey, Set<Object> keysToFetch) {
        List<LatestInits> values = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> prefixedKeys = keysToFetch.stream()
                .map(key -> key)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Object> results = redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet(prefixedKeys);

        for (Object result : results) {
            if (result instanceof String) {
                String json = (String) result;

                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                try {
                    LatestInits latestInits = objectMapper.readValue(json, LatestInits.class);
                    values.add(latestInits);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
```

Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/getLatestInits")
    public ResponseEntity<List<LatestInits>> getLatestInits() {
        try {
            Set<Object> keysToFetch = latestInitsService.readSortedSetIDsByScoreAsc("latestInits:timestamps", 0, 1691582447);
            List<LatestInits> values = latestInitsService.getValuesForKeys(Collections.singleton(keysToFetch.toString()));
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String message = e.getMessage();
            log.debug(message);
            log.error("Cannot load latest inits from the database. The database server is currently unavailable.");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
```

RedisConfig:

```
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
```

in the Service

```
List<Object> results = redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet(prefixedKeys);
```

results has size but "All elements are null"